# PHP json_encode - merging

Tags: php, json

I have 2 seperate JSON objects that I need to merge into one JSON object. Here's my first one:

```
$record['item'] = 'sp42423';
$record['manufacturer'] = 'sutherland spares';
$record['uuid_temp'] = '2F6B5511-7373-44B6-90E5-64271974BF92';

$data['fieldData'] =  $record;
$data_json = json_encode ($data);
```

which returns:

```
{
    "fieldData": {
        "item": "sp42423",
        "manufacturer": "sutherland spares",
        "uuid_temp": "2F6B5511-7373-44B6-90E5-64271974BF92"
    }
}
```

and my second JSON:

```
 $arr = array('script' => 'postRequestScript', 'script.param' => '2F6B5511-7373-44B6-90E5-64271974BF92');
```

which returns:

```
{
    "script": "postRequestScript",
    "script.param": "2F6B5511-7373-44B6-90E5-64271974BF92"
}
```

I'm after one JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
  "fieldData": {
    "item": "sp42423", 
    "manufacturer": "sutherland spares", 
    "uuid_temp": "2F6B5511-7373-44B6-90E5-64271974BF92"
  }, 
  "script": "postRequestScript", 
  "script.param": "2F6B5511-7373-44B6-90E5-64271974BF92"
}
```

but can't work out how to generate this either in a single json_encode call or by somehow merging these together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `array_merge()` on your arrays before converting them to JSON:

```
 $data_json = json_encode (array_merge($data, $arr));
```